# How to maintain global states created dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to Display list of items with then name and button to download its respective file
Same list are available in different other screens. When I click on download

1. State info sharing: It should start download and the state/progress of the download should be visible to same item available in different other screens.unique identifier is item id
2. There can be parallel downloads

Problem statement:

1. Unable to share the information for same item if we use state within the same item
2. On use of redux its solving problem 1 however Parallel download information is getting overwritten as its writing to same reducer state

Any idea or approach is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think by adding a new flag to your list of objects like "isDownloading", your problem gets solved.

1- You have a major list like :

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  name: 'song number one',
  description: 'lablab lablab ...' ,
  isDownloading:false, // this flag can help
  url:'url to download this music',
  .
  .
  .
 },
 {
  id:2,
  name: 'song number two',
  description: 'lablab lablab ...' ,
  isDownloading:true, // this flag can help
  url:'url to download this music',
  .
  .
  .
 },
 ...
]
```

2- in every screen, you can express in-progress items by fetching data with the flag "isDownloading: true" like this:

```
const desiredList = majorListTakenFromRedux.filter((music) => {
  return music.isDownloading === true;
});
```

**Every** time a client wants to download or stop downloading an item, you can update the whole list by updating the object in redux

**You** can also have another flag to handle another state like "pause" etc, ...
so maybe it is better to use the number for "isDownloading" flag.